# How many two-digit numbers yield a perfect square when added to a number with the same digits but in the reverse order?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

My last discrete math quiz included this question:

How many two-digit numbers yield a perfect square when added to a number with the same digits but in the reverse order? (An example of such a number is $83$ because $83 + 38 = 121 = 11^2$.)

I know that there are $90$ two-digit numbers, but I am not sure how to deal with the perfect square requirement.

Comment: On my very first guess, I found $56 + 65 = 121$.  So now we know there are at least two 2-digit integers that satisfy this property.

Comment: Are we including numbers with leading zeros? If so $00 = 0^2$ If not there are 8  more and they all sum to $121 = 11^2$.  I'm not claiming any mathematical insight here just it is easy to test every possible alternative in seconds with a spreadsheet.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 6):

$$(10x+y)+(10y+x)=k^2$$

$$11(x+y) = k^2$$

$$(x+y)=11\lambda^2$$

$$x+y \le 18 \implies \lambda^2=1$$

$$x+y=11$$

$$(x,y) = \{(2,9),(3,8),(4,7),(5,6),(6,5),(7,4),(8,3),(9,2)\}$$

Answer (score 1):

So, we need $$11(x+y)$$ to be perfect square

$$\implies x+ y$$ must be of the form $$11a^2$$ where $a$ an integer

Now $0<x,y<10$

Answer (score 0):

Two digit integers can be expressed as $a*10 + b*1$ for some integers $a, b$ satisfying $1 \leq a, b \leq 9$. For example, $95$ is $9*10 + 5*1$.

Now, the "reverse order" integer of $a*10 + b*1$ is $b*10 + a*1$.  For example, $59$ is $5*10 + 9*1$, and $95$ is $9*10 + 5*1$.

So, from the question, we want $10a + b + 10b + a = c^{2}$ for some $c$.

So, we are looking for integers $a$ and $b$ each between $1$ and $9$ so that $10(a + b) + a + b = c^{2}$ for some integer $c$, that is, $11(a + b) = c^{2}$, i.e., $a + b = c^{2}/11$.  Maybe from here you can plug in all possible combinations?  There would only be 81 to check.  Like $a = 1, b = 1$, $a = 1, b = 2$, etc.